# How to clear dictionary using state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Thats my function that I using to change State and "subj" is a copy of Subjects, but when I clicking it's doesn't go back to normal. What should I do?

```js
let subj  = {
    "Mathematics": false,
    "Physics": false,
    "Ukranian": false,
    "English": false,
    "Chemistry": false,
    "Informatics": false,
    "History": false
}
function ref(sub) {
    console.log({...Subjects})
    SetSubjects({Subjects: subj})
    SetSubjects({...Subjects, [sub]: true})
};
```

```js
const [Subjects, SetSubjects] = useState({
    "Mathematics": false,
    "Physics": false,
    "Ukranian": false,
    "English": false,
    "Chemistry": false,
    "Informatics": false,
    "History": false
})
```

[image]

When I clicking it keeps the same

Comment: what do you mean by normal? what are you expecting to happen

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may find it easier for us to understand what problem you're facing by adding in the component as a [mcve]. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting that when `SetSubjects` is called, `Subjects` will immediately be the new value you set, and then you try to use that new value in the subsequent  `SetSubjects` call. This is a common beginner's error. Whilst it looks like that would update `Subjects` straight away, this is actually not the case because in react state updates are queued until the next render.

So when you do this:

```
SetSubjects({Subjects: subj})
SetSubjects({...Subjects, [sub]: true})
```

`Subjects` on the second line will still be the old state from even before the first one was called. Because it does not update immediately. Only on next rerender, will `Subjects` reflect the new value.

You want to do it in a single state transition, and not create dependencies between state setter calls, as that won't work due to state updates being asynchronous and not synchronous.

Replace both lines with:

```
SetSubjects({...subj, [sub]: true})
```

Comment: no I want every time I press the button the `Subjects` becomes default, because when I clicking second time on another `btn`  the other `btn` should be true and I don't need old one,(For example I clicking on `Mathematics`, `Mathematics` going `true` and after I click on `English`, `Mathematics` should be `false` and `English` `true`) so the `subj` is the original form of `Subjects`

Comment: Correct, the above change should achieve exactly that in one transition -- try it :). Its also important to note your console.log should've in the main component body (in render), so you see the latest changes and not the previous ones.